# Pass coordinates from service to directive with angular

Tags: angularjs, google-maps-api-3

I made a directive for my google maps on my angular application. The latitude and longtitude are hard coded in the directive. I'm trying to get those coordinates from my service just the same as I get the location name and description.

```
<h2 class="page-title">{{ locationInfo.name }}</h2>

<img ng-src="{{ locationInfo.images[0].scenic}}" alt="">

<p>{{ locationInfo.description }}</p>

<gmap id ="map-canvas" class="map"></gmap>
```

My directive is currently looking like this which gives a static map instead of changing dynamically

```
.directive("gmap", function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        replace: true,
        template: '<div></div>',
        link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
            var latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(40, -73);
            var mapOptions = {
                zoom: 15,
                center: latLng,
                mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
            };

            var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById(attrs.id), mapOptions);

            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: latLng,
                map: map
            });
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Do you have a controller implementing/using your directive and view?

Comment: I only have a controller for my view where I deal with data from a resolve

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, instead of using document.getElementById you should make use of the "element" atribute which you inject in your link function. That "element" is your angular object corresponding to your DOM element. If you can't use it, then go ahead using document.getElementById, but change the "id" dynamically.

Also, if you want to use it as a directive I would suggest to use two attributes for your latitude and longitude, and naming your id dynamically using some property of your locationInfo object:

```
<gmap id ="map-canvas_{{locationInfo.name}}" lat="locationInfo.lat" lon="locationInfo.lon" class="map"></gmap>
```

where locationInfo contains latitude and longitude info named as lat and lon.

Then in your directive, you read your tag atritubes via the attrs object:

```
.directive("gmap", function () {
   return {
       ...
       // Here you read your tag attributes "lat" and "lon"
       link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
            var latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(attrs.lat, attrs.lon);
            // Here you can use the injected "element" instead of "document.getElementById(attrs.id)" but it seems it doesn't work for you
            var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById(attrs.id), mapOptions);
       }
   }
 });
```

Also I recomend to define your variables using comma "," as in:

```
 var a = something,
     b = somethingElse,
     c = anything;
```

instead of using several "var" sentences. This is a good practice.

Hope this helps.

Comment: doesn't the 'var map' needs to be inside the link? I'm also getting this strange error when changing the getElementById to just element: Uncaught TypeError: Failed to execute 'getComputedStyle' on 'Window': parameter 1 is not of type 'Element'.

Comment: Oh sorry!!! you're right... typo there. In case you need to use plain element via getElementById I suggest you generate your id. Editing.. there you go